# Can anyone Tell me how to get uid/token using flutter firebase phone authentication?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Can anyone Tell me how to get uid/token using flutter firebase phone authentication?

I am able to authenticate but i dont know how to get uid so i can send my fetch and get requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once Authenticated, you are able to get the UID of a user via:

```
final FirebaseUser user = await auth.currentUser();
final uid = user.uid;
```